# Prove by the definition of continuity that $f(x) = x^4 - 4x$ is continuous at $x_0 = 2$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, continuity

Using the definition of continuity at a point, prove that $f(x) = x^4 - 4x $ is continuous at $x_0 =2$.

ny attempt:

pick $ \epsilon > 0 $ need $ \delta > 0 $ such that $|x-2| < \delta $ implies $| x^4 - 4x - (2^4 -4*2) | < \epsilon$

$$| x^4 - 4x - (2^4 - 4*2)| = |x^4 - 4x +8|$$

I know that I want to be able to factor out $|x-2|$ so that I can fix $\delta$ and find $\epsilon$, and then I am good from there. I just am not sure how to manipulate the expression to factor out an $|x-2|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you made a mistake in your computations: $x^4-4x-(2^4-4\times2)=x^2-4x\color{red}{-}8$, And now, using Ruffini's rule or polynomial long division, you can get that$$x^4-4x-8=(x-2)(x^3+2x^2+4x+4).$$

Comment: Thanks a bunch!

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$| x^4 - 4x - (2^4 - 4*2)| = |x^4 - 4x -8|=|x-2||x^3+2x^2+4x+4|$$

Now you can work with  Your $|x-2|<\delta$